# dijit Tree JsonRest, new Items shows on all Nodes

Tags: javascript, rest, tree, dojo, new-item

i want to use a dojo/data/JsonRest to display a Tree.
Load from Server works fine, but if i add a new Item, the new Item is displayed on each openend node. The request is made to the server an the response looks good for me.
On the Serverside i use PHP with SlimFramwork

The Javascript is as follows:

```
require([
     "dojo/parser",
     "dojo/_base/array",
     "dojo/on", 
     "dijit/registry",
     "dojo/store/JsonRest",
     "dojo/store/Observable",
    "dijit/Tree",
    "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel",

    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(parser, array, on, registry, JsonRest, Observable, Tree, ObjectStoreModel
        ){
    parser.parse();

    var reststore = new JsonRest({
        target: "Antrag/",
        getChildren: function(object){
            console.dir(object);
            return this.query({parent: object.id});
        }
    });
    var reststore=new Observable(reststore);



    var treeModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
        store: reststore,
        //labelAttr: "anzeige",
        query: {
            jahr: 2015,
            nummer: 1, 
            antArt: 1,
            kb: 58,
            antArt: 1,
            tree: true
        },
        mayHaveChildren: function(object){
            return true;
        },
        getLabel : function(item) {
            console.dir(item);
            console.log(item.typ);
            if(item!=null){
                //console.dir(item);
                if (item.typ == "KE") {
                    if (item.posten == "0") {
                        rueckgabe = "Keine Postennr";
                    } else {
                        rueckgabe = item.posten;
                    }
                } else if (item.typ == "KD" || item.typ == "NL" || item.typ == "ADDR") {
                    //console.log(item.typ+" "+item.Bezeichnung);
                    rueckgabe = item.Bezeichnung;
                } else if (item.typ.substring(0,6)=="antrag") {
                    this._antrag=item;
                    rueckgabe = item.anzeige;
                } else {
                    //console.log(item.typ+" "+item.anzeige);
                    rueckgabe = item.anzeige;
                }
                return rueckgabe;
            }else{
            return false;
            }

        },

    });
    var tree = new dijit.Tree({
        model : treeModel,
        autoExpand: true
        }, 'treeNode');

        tree.startup();

    on(registry.byId('butAdd'), "click", function(e){
        var selectedObject = tree.get("selectedItems")[0];
         var LS={
                 typ: "LS",
                 //antrag: selectedObject.id,
                 //antrag: this._antrag.id,
                 berechnung: selectedObject.id,
                 neu: true,
                 //parent: selectedObject.id
             };
        reststore.put({
            typ: "LS",
            //antrag: selectedObject.id,
            //antrag: this._antrag.id,
            berechnung: selectedObject.id,
            neu: true,
        }, {parent: selectedObject});

    })

});
```

All Items that are loaded at startup looks fine. Everything is at the right place.

The Request for a new Item (from Web-Developer) looks like this:

```
berechnung:"Rech234647"
neu:true
typ:"LS"
```

The response from Server is:

```
{"id":"LS234647_1","berechnungId":"234647","typ":"LS","parent":"Rech234647",anzeige":"Lieferschein 1"}
```

I don't understand why the new item is displayed under all opened Nodes. If i do a delete, all Representations of the new Node are deleted inside the Tree.

Comment: @Drik Can you setup a fiddler to view the behaviour?

Comment: @TKambi i Have an example as an fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/neupertd/jp14psez/)

Comment: @TKambi i solved it with Surround in csche-store

Answer (score 0):

The Goal is to use an Cachestore to provide all methods for querying the store.

```
require([
     "dojo/parser",
     "dojo/_base/array",
     "dojo/on", 
     "dijit/registry",
     "dojo/store/JsonRest",
     "dojo/store/Memory",
     "dojo/store/Observable",
     "dojo/store/Cache",
    "dijit/Tree",
    "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel",

    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(parser, array, on, registry, JsonRest, Memory, Observable, Cache, Tree, ObjectStoreModel
        ){
    parser.parse();

    var reststore1 = new JsonRest({
        target: "Antrag/",
        getChildren: function(object){
            console.dir(object);
            return this.query({parent: object.id});
        }
    });
    var memorystore=new Memory();

    var reststore=new Observable(new Cache(reststore1, memorystore));

    var treeModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
        store: reststore,
        query: {
            jahr: 2015,
            nummer: 1, 
            antArt: 1,
            kb: 58,
            antArt: 1,
            tree: true
        },
        mayHaveChildren: function(object){
            return true;
        },
        getLabel : function(item) {
            console.dir(item);
            console.log(item.typ);
            if(item!=null){
                if (item.typ == "KE") {
                    if (item.posten == "0") {
                        rueckgabe = "Keine Postennr";
                    } else {
                        rueckgabe = item.posten;
                    }
                } else if (item.typ == "KD" || item.typ == "NL" || item.typ == "ADDR") {
                    rueckgabe = item.Bezeichnung;
                } else if (item.typ.substring(0,6)=="antrag") {
                    this._antrag=item;
                    rueckgabe = item.anzeige;
                } else {
                    rueckgabe = item.anzeige;
                }
                return rueckgabe;
            }else{
            return false;
            }
        },

    });
    var tree = new dijit.Tree({
        model : treeModel,
        autoExpand: true
        }, 'treeNode');

        tree.startup();

    on(registry.byId('butAdd'), "click", function(e){
        var selectedObject = tree.get("selectedItems")[0];
         var LS={
                 typ: "LS",
                 berechnung: selectedObject.id,
                 neu: true,
             };
        reststore.put({
            typ: "LS",
            berechnung: selectedObject.id,
            neu: true,
        }, {parent: selectedObject});

    })

});
```

I'll update my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jp14psez/31/